# Is this a valid either-or sentence?

Tags: word-usage, either-or

I read this a few days ago:

**... individuals who log on and float either instead of or in addition to scheduling hours.**

I suppose it sounds awkward to me because I tend to think that in a sentence of the type "either X or Y" both X and Y ought to be nouns.

So, does this sentence is written in good English and it is only my faultfinding bone what is trying to make me see something that is not there?

Let me thank you in advance for your attention and support.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Grammatical, but a nightmare to parse.